# a question regarding gradients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I had a question in my exam, in which I had to practically find the gradient of a function in a certain point, thing is one of the vectors becomes 0 and I can't figure out how this happened,
it says that a person is climbing a mountain in that is given by a function,
the function is 
$$z=f(x,y)=e^{-x^2-y^2+11}$$ 
the direction is in the direction of the contour lines of the function, he is standing in the point of $$(1,-3,e)$$
so I have to find the "next step" he has to take.
I'd be thankful if you'd help me figure this out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? How do you get a vector becoming 0 fx? I can't help noting the $e^{-x^2-x^2}$ part which means that it's rotationally symmetric function - he should go towards the origin.

Comment: I've tried to find the partial derivatives of the function, then try to find the gradient but I get a wrong answer, in the right answer the k vector becomes 0, so it's 3i+j,
I'm trying to build a new function and then find its partial derivatives, but this is not going well too..

Comment: is this why the k vector becomes 0?

Comment: What is the "$k$" vector. And what is these $i$ and $j$?. Is the $k$ the $z$ part of the vector? Then it's obviously not 0, it's just not mentioned (you have to go up to climb the mountain - that's taken for granted).

Comment: @Marie After writing the answer, I see, by your comments, that there is some confusion as to where "lives" the gradient. The gradient vector has the same dimension as the number of variables, i.e. 2.

Comment: ohhh this makes sense now, I totally forgot about the dimension.. but still I can't get the right answer... 
as to the i, k and j those are the vectors this is how we're used to write an answer that represents vectors..

Comment: Of course $3i+j$ is the horrible physicists' notation for $(3,1)$ :)

Comment: my whole uni is horrible xD, they didn't explain half of what you did now, and I still get this in my exam, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In exams, it is important to read precisely the question. If you are asking for the gradient, it is defined as the vector of partial derivatives $\nabla f=\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$:
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}= -2\, x\, e^{-x^2-y^2+11}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}= -2\, y\, e^{-x^2-y^2+11}$$

Now, substituting at the the point $(1,-3)$ you get the vector:
$$\nabla f(1,-3)=(-2e,6e)$$

EDIT: I understand that the question asks for a vector that is tangent to the contour lines, i.e. the lines where the function remain constant. If the function is constant, then its directional derivative in that direction vanishes. But the directional derivative can be computed as $D_v f = \nabla f \cdot v$ so $D_v f=0$ implies that the vector $v$ and the gradient are orthogonal or, in other words, that the cosine of the angle they form is null. So the correct answer is any vector that is orthogonal to the gradient, e.g. $(3,1)$.

Comment: this is what I did in the exam, it's a wrong answer unfortunately, 
the right answer would be 3i+j, I really don't get the question, so I roughly translated it...

Comment: @Marie Let me guess: maybe the question was "find a vector such that the slope in that direction is null", or "find a vector that is orthogonal to the gradient", or "find a vector that is tangent to the contour lines"...

Comment: yes that's what I meant by he's going in the direction of the contour lines.
sorry for my bad English and bad translation

Comment: @Marie Which language was the original question? I can manage in French...

Comment: Hebrew, and it's not even my native language this is why I'm struggling so much

Comment: I get it now! thanks a lot!